# Does multithreaded memory access improve performance?

Tags: multithreading, performance, memory

I have a large array in RAM and want to read data from it as fast as possible. Ignore any possible synchronization, I only wonder about the theory.

Is it faster to spread those reads over several threads than just using one?

Edit: the data points are about 20KB each and I can't predict in which order they are read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking: **yes** but *beware of cache misses*.

Let's say that you have an int[]: consider partitioning it in ranges of subsequent elements and have each thread get a range of its own (thread1 get from 0 to 127, thread2 from 128 to 255, ...).

When you read one element of the array, the processor core executing the load is most likely to load some of the successive elements of the array in its *cache*, because most of the times they are going to be needed right after (immagine *for (int i =0;;i++) do(arra[i])*): if you don't partition your data in a **coarse** way, all this work is going to be wasted.

You can read more about this in the following articles from Joe Duffy:

- [Using concurrency for scalability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163552.aspx)
- [Solving 11 Likely Problems In Your Multithreaded Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc817398.aspx)

Not strictly related: [The 'premature optimization is evil' myth](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2010/09/06/ThePrematureOptimizationIsEvilMyth.aspx) in particular the part "Understand the order of magnitude that matters"

As @Alex said, the general rule is that you have to *always measure* and never assume anything: efficient scalability via concurrency is a complex subject and requires a lot of deep understaing of the underlying architecture.

Comment: I don't think data locality is of much use since my elements are large and accessed in a random fashion. But does this mean that the connection between the processor and the memory allows for parallel execution of reads if the data exists in different parts of the memory?

Comment: Well, if your data points are that size, the answer is definately yes! Remember to pad the array elements to the nearest multiple of processor word size (misaligning can be significant sometime).

Comment: Does the connection between the processor and the memory allow for parallel execution of reads if the data exists in different parts of the memory?

Comment: I think so, that depends on the architecture of the Front-side bus / northbridge. I'm not an expert but I found interesting articles: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_controller and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-side_bus#Transfer_rates The bandwidth at that layer is huge  :)

Comment: The flip-side of locality in multi-threaded situations is false sharing. As well as wanting to have each thread deal with a coarse block when possible so that each enjoys better locality, you also don't want thread 0 writing to position x when thread 1 might be reading or writing position x+1, if x and x+1 will be in the same cache-line, or thread 0 will cause thread 1s cache-line to need to be refreshed even though the value it cares about won't be changed. This sort of false sharing can result with exponentially worse behaviour as more cores are added.

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes. You can use more threads to read from different places in memory. CPU is faster so it could issues lots of reads, say one read per thread, until the result from the first read comes back. Then start processing the requests. 
This works assuming the RAM doesn't block; ie supports multiple reads at once. It, for example, your memory has only 1 input line and 1 output line, then it would be blocking and no amount of threads would help.

Now keep in mind what exactly you do with that data that you read. If you are sending it over a network synchronously or dumping it to HDD, it doesn't necessarily mean you should use multithreading to read the data since it will bottleneck on write_to_HDD/sendData.

If you have another CPU waiting to process the data retrieved then you could paralyze well. Read and process at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Just test it for your specific situation. Context switching of thread's is expensive afterall. And you might be just as fast using a single-threaded method.

Measure performance, don't guess it.

Comment: I have made a simple test and the results are inconclusive - sometimes I get performance gains, other times absolutely nothing. That's why I wanted to know the theory.

Comment: Have you considered the "jit-warmup" and comparable/measurable test runs? If you could post your test code that would help for sure.

Comment: Yeah, that test could definitely use some improvements with proper JIT warmup and averaging over several test runs. The code is quite ugly, wouldn't really want to spread it but I'll make those changes and run the test again later. Thanks!